# vagrant. ошибка при vagrant up

Tags: php, yii2, yii, vagrant

При запуске получаю ошибку: `папка vagrant/config пустая`. Я не могу понять,  что я  не так делаю? Может быть забыли включить необходимые файлы в проект?

*Сообщение об ошибке ниже:*

```
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /var/www/hatimaki_salary/hatimaki_salary/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./vagrant/config/vagrant-local.example.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня появилось сообщение это, хотя вчера вечером всё работало. Подумал, что обновление Windows. Поставил новую версию vagrant, не помогло. Получил токен с github, не помогло.

Решилось тем, что я зашел в папку с Vagrantfile( Но не тот, который идет с Yii2, а тот, который я делал на puphpet.com,   если мой сайт лежит в D:\web\test, то я зашел в D:\web\y
И сделал **vagrant reload**

Сайт заработал, ошибка пропала.

Возможно у тебя проблемы с SSH, но этот вариант я не рассматривал, так как ошибка пропала.